# Throw error if config object doesn't contain all required properties

Tags: javascript

I have an ES6 class that require a config object. 
If a property is missing, I'd like to throw an error.

The solution if found to keep the code short and not add a `if(!object.propN)...` for every property is to do :

```
class myClass {
  constructor(config) {
    if (!config) {
      throw new Error("You must provide a config object");
    }

    this.prop1 = config.prop1;
    this.prop2 = config.prop2;
    this.prop3 = config.prop3;
    this.prop4 = config.prop4;

    for (const key in this) {
      if (!this[key]) {
        throw new Error(`Config object miss the property ${key}`);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Is it OK to do this in javascript ?

Comment: does this `if (!this[key]) {` implies that non of the `config` properties may be empty(all props should be filled)?

Comment: Yes, all properties should be non-empty strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For configs, we usually use the feature `Destructuring assignment` to check whether the properties are in an object or not by using the sugar of ES6 (ES2015).

And furthermore, we can also set default values for the configs by this feature.

```
{prop1, prop2, prop3: path='', prop4='helloworld', ...others} = config
```

After destructuring assignment has been done, just need to do a check before what we are going to do with the specific config. i.e.

```
if (!prop1) {
  throw new Error(`Config object miss the property ${prop1}`);
}
doSomething(prop1);
```

But if you still want to check all the configs at the beginning, you can do something like this,

```
class myClass {
  constructor(config) {
    if (!config) {
      throw new Error("You must provide a config object");
    }

    // You can assign the values to a new object like "tmpConfig" or just assign them back to "config" for the case config.propX === undefined
    ({prop1: config.prop1=undefined, prop2: config.prop2=undefined, prop3: config.prop3=undefined, prop4: config.prop4=undefined} = config);

    for (const key in config) {
      if (!config[key]) {
        throw new Error(`Config object miss the property ${key}`);
      }
    }

    Object.assign(this, config);
  }
}
```

Or only using Object.assign() by setting default values,

```
class myClass {
  constructor(config) {
    if (!config) {
      throw new Error("You must provide a config object");
    }

    let requiredConfigs = {
      prop1: undefined,
      prop2: undefined,
      prop3: undefined,
      prop4: undefined,
    }
    let tmpConfig = Object.assign(requiredConfigs, config);

    for (const key in tmpConfig) {
      if (!tmpConfig[key]) {
        throw new Error(`Config object miss the property ${key}`);
      }
    }

    Object.assign(this, tmpConfig);
  }
}
```

=> **We use Destructuring assignment and Object.assign() a lot for doing setting configs things.**

Answer (score 0):

To avoid premature and excessive setting of all `config` properties into `this` object you should place the check for an empty property occurrence beforehand. 
The solution using `Array.some` function:

```
class myClass {
  constructor(config) {
    if (!config || typeof config !== "object") {
        throw new Error("You must provide a config object!");
    } else if (Object.keys(config).some((k) => !config[k])) {  // returns 'true' if any empty property is found
        throw new Error(`Config object has empty property(ies)!`);
    }

    this.prop1 = config.prop1;
    this.prop2 = config.prop2;
    this.prop3 = config.prop3;
    this.prop4 = config.prop4;

  }
}
```